# Unable to call windows and dialogs from MainWindow

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I've added a new window to the solution (Add -> new window)
to start it I wrote:

```
Wndw1 w = new Wndow1 ();
w.Show ();
```

But it gives an error

```
/home/spam/del2/del2/jhj.cs(3,3): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Wndw1' could not be found. Are you missing `del2' using directive? (CS0246) (del2)
```

Even though, the code works in any class other than MainWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You create a new gtk# project, main window will appear automatically
when you create a class later it will be in the namespace, while mainwindow won't
so..add a namespace!

Comment: namespace must be added automatically!

Comment: Just check your class -_-